# A Worker running in the background for knockoutjs vewmodel

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, web-worker

I have a viewmodel for a knockoutjs component. In the viewmodel, there is a function `init()` that executes for several minutes. Because of this, the UI of the component on the browser freezes until the `init()` finishes its execution.

```
function myViewModel(){
   self = this;
   self.x = ko.observable(0);
   self.y = ko.observableArray([]);
   self.z = ko.observable({});

   self.init = function(){
     //Need to use JQuery here
     //loading stuff from DB via JQuery ajax
     //assign retrieved data to x and y and z
   }

}
```

Is there a way to run `init()` in the background?

I looked at the possibility of `Worker`, which runs in the background, but `Worker` needs to use JQuery. If I pass JQuery (and several other JSON objects) to worker via postMessage, like this: `worker.postMessage($)`, then I get the error:

**Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': An object could not be cloned.**

Any idea how to make `init()` run in the background to avoid frozen UI?

I tried timeout, like below, but UI still freezes:

```
self.executeAsync = function(func) {
      setTimeout(func, 0);
};
self.executeAsync(self.init);
```

Comment: You can probably pass `x`, `y` and `z` to the worker using `worker.postMessage({x, y, z})` or something.

Comment: @Xufox How, specifically? Also, how would I catch it back in the viewmodel?

Comment: It depends on what `init` actually does to `x`, `y` and `z`… and what else that function does… but generally you can send a worker anything that it needs to know and the worker does its thing. Then the worker sends back the result and the main thread uses the result. It doesn’t work with DOM operations for example…

Comment: init() just assigns the data (retrieved from database via jquery.ajax) to x,y and z. When I put init() in a worker, my troubles are: 1) how to make it be able to use jquery? 2) pass the x,y z back to the viewmodel. If you can clarify these two questions, that would be great.

Comment: You should be using async ajax requests so that `init` doesn't freeze the UI. Sounds like you're not doing that.

Comment: Well, jQuery can be imported with [`importScripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) in the Worker. To pass anything to the main thread you first have to add a `message` event listener to the worker object in the main thread and deal with the result there, then in the worker thread use `postMessage`.

Comment: @Xufox OK. Understood.

Comment: But apparently importing jQuery doesn’t work because it requires a `window` object to run. And then jQuery is primarily for DOM manipulation, so there’s not much use in importing it anyway.

Comment: but I need JQuery to do ajax

Comment: in the viewmodel I have JQuery. Is JQuery still visible to the worker without explicitly importing it inside the worker?

Comment: If you just want to avoid freezing of screen while `init()` is loading, then you can do same thing using javascript [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)/asynchronous model.

Comment: Well, i used promises in Jquery in my ajax calls already. `$.getJSON( url).then(function (response)`  But the thing is I need to make such 5000 ajax calls inside init(). Please don't ask why I need to make that many calls :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises.

As for the comments, your problem is that you know how to use all the ajax promises, but you don't know how to implement your own promise.

As you're using jQuery, let's do it with this library. It's only 3 steps

1. create a deferred object like this: `var deferred = $.Deferred();`
2. return a promise from this deferred, so that you can use `.then` to include the callbacks when the promise is resolve or rejected. For example: `return deferred.promise();` or, if you're returning and object, you can return the promise as a member of that object, to check for completion: `return { ..., promise = deferred.promise()};`
3. When your code succeeds or fails, resolve or reject your promise, like this: `deferred.resolve();` or `deferred.reject();`

In your case, create a deferred at the beginning of `init()`, and when all the jQuery ajax are completed, resolve the promise, or reject it, if something goes wrong.

Some notes on `Deferred` functionality:

1. If you resolve (or reject) your deferred passing an object, you'll receive that object as a parameter for your callback
2. You can return an object wrapped in a promise. For example, if your `init()` returns an object (for example an object implementing an API), you can return that object wrapped in a promise like this: `return deferred.promise(retVal);`
3. The implementation of jQuery promises is not Promises/A+ compatible until version 3.0. That has to do with chaining and exception propagation in callback chains. It will not affect you for this case. In the meantime, you can use other promises libraries like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), or [rsvp](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/), which are Promises/A+ compatible, and implement more functionalities.
4. You can use `deferred.notify` to signal progress. Then you can specify a `progress` callback

Documentation for [jQuery's Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Pseudo code:

```
init: function() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  // run your stuff, for example with setTimeout() or setInterval()
  // so that the code follows running on the same line
  // eventually, your stuff will resolve or reject the deferred/promise
  return deferrer.promise();
}
```

Then you can use callbacks with your init, like usual: `init().then(...)`;

As you don't explain what your init function does, it's not clear if you have to update some observables, or show some controls or whatever when the promise is resolved. That's up to you.

**NOTE**: I'm afraid you can be doing something wrong if you manipulate DOM objects with jQuery: when using knockout, all the DOM manipulation should be solved with ko bindings. Mixing up both ways of DOM manipulation can soon become cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

You can import jQuery to the `Worker` script with `importScripts()`.

At the top of your `Worker` script, just put `importScripts('path/to/jQuery')` and you'll have access to jQuery. The `importScripts` function is a global function in the `WorkerGlobalScope` interface, so all your workers should have access to it.